# Soul Cairn: Constant Health Drain

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I've been training restoration just outside the Soul Cairn portal inside the Volikhar Balcony and I reloaded my save to continue training and now my character is experiencing constant health depletion. (Keep in mind my character is now a werewolf, meaning I can't enter the Soul Cairn.) I've researched this problem and I'm aware that this is a glitch. Is there a known solution to solve this problem other than reloading a previous save?

Comment: No, I'm playing on xbox 360. @desaivv

Answer (score 2):

What were you before you were being injured?

- If you're a vampire, you're fine to go through normally.
- If you allow your soul to be partially put away in a soul gem, you're also
  fine, (from quest).

But once you become a human or a werewolf, you have your soul back.
Now this place feeds on souls, so its feeding off your life essence, thus taking your life away.

The only thing you can do is take many potions with you, many magika and health potions so you can use health restore magic too.  I had to go back in as a human and it was taking my life away, I used many potions and magic to get through without dying.

Comment: I completed the storyline as a Vampire Lord initially, I then decided to become a Werewolf. There wasn't anything I could do other than reloading a previous save.

Comment: yeah its a huge bummer, i too became human and tried going there but i had constant health drain, i endured it with magic and potions,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'll respond with what worked for me so that others can find it.
I was in the Soul Cairn as a vampire lord and randomly started taking constant health drain without any negative magic effects listed. The effect continued outside of the Soul Cairn as well. I tried a bunch of stuff and all that worked was making a mad dash for Solitude and praying at one of the shrines (I used the shrine of Kynareth, not sure if that matters). I happened to have a ton of potions and modded food and skooma stored up in my inventory which kept me going until I could make it.