# Why do I die so easily after the Soul Cairn missions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After the Soul Cairn missions I got my soul back, but I keep dying way to easily to people I used to be able to beat easily.

Comment: Was your armor unequipped?

Comment: Are you encountering the bug described in these questions? [Soul Cairn: Constant Health Drain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95386/4797) [Health is draining even after leaving the Soul Cairn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/249025/4797)

Comment: @pausepause yeah my armor is equipped

Comment: @glacticninja no mine is different

Comment: More details such as what your max health is/was, your armor levels, and any statuses you might be suffering would be helpful to solving your issue. Simple "I keep dying after soul cairn" isn't a lot to go off of.

Comment: What level is your character? You may have hit a difficulty milestone that makes enemies stronger, just coinciding with you leaving the soul cairn